# How do I post a node to PayPal after node insert/update?

Tags: 7, payment-gateways

I have an option in my node to "upgrade".

If the user selects this option either when creating a new node or updating an existing node, I would like to post the node data (which includes some Paypal html elements) to Paypal so that it can process a payment.

The node should be inserted/saved regardless of the payment result. I need to specify via Paypal what the return URL is and with inserting node's I wont know that until after the node is inserted.

Is there a way to post to 2 places? I know that doesnt really make sense but im just looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send this information and get and `nid`, the best place to do this is in:

- [`hook_node_insert()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) to execute this action just after inserting the node and to have a `nid`.
- [`hook_node_update()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7) to execute this action just after updating the node.